# Complex Join Query Giving Error

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sqlfiddle

I tried to run a complex join query on SQLFiddle but kept getting errors. Wanted to print all the main attributes on the select statement. Got stuck for the past few days. A helping hand will much appreciated.

```
`CREATE TABLE Customer`
`(CustomerID INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
`FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`
`LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`
`StreetAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`
`Apartment VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`
`City VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`
`State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,`
`ZipCode CHAR(9) NOT NULL,`
`HomePhone CHAR(10) NOT NULL,`
`MobilePhone CHAR(10) NOT NULL,`
`OtherPhone CHAR(10) NOT NULL,`
`PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));`
`INSERT INTO Customer `
`(FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, Apartment, City, State,`
`ZipCode, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone)`
`VALUES ('Max', 'Karl', '101 Main', ' ABC ', 'ABC', `
`'TX', 77077, 12345, 987654, 963258);`
`SELECT CustomerID, (CONCAT (firstname, ' ', Lastname)) as FullName,` `StreetAddress, Apartment, City, State, ZipCode, Homephone, `mobilephone,`otherphone FROM customer;`

`CREATE TABLE Donut`
`(DonutID INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
`Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`
`Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`
`UnitPrice DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,`
`PRIMARY KEY (DonutID));`
`INSERT INTO Donut (Name, Description, UnitPrice)`
`VALUES ('Plain', 'Plain Donut', '1.50'),`
`('Glazed', 'Glazed Donut', '1.75'),`
`('Cinnamon', 'Cinnamon Donut', '1.75'),`
`('Chocolate', 'Chocolate Donut', '1.75'),`
`('Sprinkle', 'Sprinkle Donut', '1.75'),`
`('Gluten-Free', 'Gluten-Free Donut', '2.00');`
`CREATE INDEX DonutName ON Donut (Name);`

`CREATE TABLE DonutOrder`
`(DonutOrderID INT (255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
`DonutID INT(255) NOT NULL,`
`Quantity INT(255),`
`PRIMARY KEY (DonutOrderID, donutID),`
`FOREIGN KEY (donutID) REFERENCES Donut(donutID),`
`INDEX Donut(donutID));`
`INSERT INTO DonutOrder (DonutID, Quantity)`
`VALUES ((SELECT DonutID FROM Donut WHERE DonutID = 1), 1),`
  ` ((SELECT DonutID FROM Donut WHERE DonutID = 2), 5),`
  ` ((SELECT DonutID FROM Donut WHERE DonutID = 3), 12),`
   `((SELECT DonutID FROM Donut WHERE DonutID = 4), 3),`
   `((SELECT DonutID FROM Donut WHERE DonutID = 5), 4),`
  ` ((SELECT DonutID FROM Donut WHERE DonutID =6), 5);`

`CREATE TABLE SalesInvoice`
`(CustomerID INT(255) NOT NULL,`
`DonutOrderID INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
`Date date NOT NULL,`
`Spec_Hnd_Inst VARCHAR(255),`
`PRIMARY KEY (DonutOrderID),`
`INDEX Customer (CustomerID),`
`FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),`
`INDEX DonutOrder (donutOrderID));`

`SELECT Customer.CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, Apartment, City, `
`State, ZipCode, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone, Donut.DonutID, Name,`
`Description, UnitPrice, DonutOrder.DonutOrderID, DonutOrder.DonutID, `
`Quantity, SalesInvoice.DonutOrderID, SalesInvoice.CustomerID`
`FROM donut JOIN Customer ON SalesInvoice.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID`
`JOIN DonutOrder ON Donut.DonutID = DonutOrder.DonutID`
`JOIN SalesInvoice ON DonutOrder.DonutID = SalesInvoice.DonutOrderID`
```

Comment: What was the error ?

Comment: If you tried on SQLFiddle then upload that link also

Comment: Just got a response from a previous post. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference the `SalesInvoice` table in your `join` before you actually `join` to it -- and therefore it doesn't exist.  You just need to change the order of your joins:

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, 
      Apartment, City, State, 
      ZipCode, HomePhone, MobilePhone, 
      OtherPhone, Donut.DonutID, Name, Description, 
      UnitPrice, DonutOrder.DonutOrderID, DonutOrder.DonutID, 
      Quantity, SalesInvoice.DonutOrderID, 
      SalesInvoice.CustomerID 
FROM donut 
  JOIN DonutOrder ON Donut.DonutID = DonutOrder.DonutID 
  JOIN SalesInvoice ON DonutOrder.DonutID = SalesInvoice.DonutOrderID
  JOIN Customer ON SalesInvoice.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eec33b/2)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified to running query as below

```
SELECT  c.*, d.*, dor.*, si.*
    FROM donut d
    left outer JOIN DonutOrder dor ON dor.DonutID = d.DonutID
    left outer JOIN SalesInvoice si ON si.DonutOrderID = si.DonutOrderID
    left outer JOIN Customer c on c.CustomerID = si.CustomerID
```